# C# closure variable scope

Tags: c#, .net

A(nother?) question about how variable scope is applied in relation to closures. Here's a minimal example:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string name;
    public Foo(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}


public class Program
{
    static Action getAction(Foo obj)
    {
        return () => Console.WriteLine(obj.name); 
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo obj1 = new Foo("x1");    
        Action a = getAction(obj1);  
        obj1 = new Foo("x2");        
        a();                         
    }
}
```

This prints `x1`. It can be explained as:

**`getAction` returns an anonymous function which has a closure enclosing the variable `obj`. `obj` has the same reference *value* as `obj1` but its relationship with `obj1` ends there as the closure encloses only `obj`. In other words, whatever value `obj1` takes afterwards does not affect the closure. Therefore whenever/however `a` gets called (eg. `a` gets passed to some other function) it will always print `x1`.**

Now my questions are:

1. Is the above explanation correct?
2. I don't have a specific scenario in mind but what if we wanted the program to print `x2` (eg. closure to enclose an outer scope)? Could it be done (or doesn't it make sense to even attempt)?

Comment: Your explanation seems obvious because you have two different variables that initially refer to the same object but then you assign a different object to one of them, which has no effect on the other.  I'm guessing that declaring your `obj` parameter as `ref` might address your second question, but I'm not 100% sure of that.

Comment: @jmcilhinney It is not allowed to capture `ref` parameter in closure.

Comment: @PetSerAl, I guess that might be to explicitly avoid the situation described here, or at least avoid the appearance that it might be possible.

Comment: @jmcilhinney IIRC, at the IL level a `Foo*` / `ref Foo` field (reference-to-a-reference, not a pointer) would be fine and understood perfectly - but that isn't a concept that can be expressed in C# (hence why I had to approximate syntax to even discuss it!), so it is perhaps reasonable that the closure has the same feature limits as hand-coding;

Comment: You've got some good answers so I won't add another. I will note that you are probably slightly misusing the word "scope". The scope of a named entity is defined as *the region of program text in which that entity may be used by name without qualification*. For example, method `Main` may not refer to `obj` because the scope of `obj` does not include method `Main`.  But `Main` can use `Foo` because the scope of a public class does include the body of `Main` in another class in the same namespace.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's consider:

```
static Action getAction(Foo obj)
{
    return () => Console.WriteLine(obj.name); 
}
```

The closure is over the *parameter* `obj`; this `obj` is a reference passed by value, so if a caller does:

```
x = someA();
var action = getAction(x);
x = someB(); // not seen by action
```

then the closure is still over the *original* value, because the reference (not the object) is *copied* when passing it to `getAction`.

Note that if the caller *changes values* on the original object, this will be seen by the method:

```
x = someA();
var action = getAction(x);
x.name = "something else"; // seen by action
```

Inside the `getAction` method, it is basically:

```
var tmp = new SomeCompilerGeneratedType();
tmp.obj = obj;
return new Action(tmp.SomeCompilerGeneratedMethod);
```

with:

```
class SomeCompilerGeneratedType {
    public Foo obj;
    public void SomeCompilerGeneratedMethod() {
        Console.WriteLine(obj.name); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you mean `tmp.SomeCompilerGeneratedMethod`. Not `obj.SomeCompilerGeneratedMethod`

Comment: Thanks.. this confirmed my understanding of how capturing works here. My second question is perhaps the most important - how can one 'expand' the closure scope eg. if one wanted to have `obj1` included in the closure scope how could it be done? I assume this could be done if we could pass the reference variable as a `ref` but this doesn't seem to be allowed.

Comment: @ubi you would need to pass in a reference to an object that has a property that is the `Foo`, then you can change the outer `parent.Foo`, and since the lambda is now capturing the `parent` reference (via the parameter), any change to members of `parent` will be visible to the lambda

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: The explanation is correct and if you want to change the value from `x1` to `x2` then you have to change the specific object that is passed to the action.

`obj1.name = 'x2'`

When an object is passed to a function as parameter it copies the reference (pointer) to the obj.

At that time you have **one** object and **two** references;

- The `Foo obj1` that is the variable in the `Main` and
- The `Foo obj` that is the variable in the `getAction`

Whenever you choose to set another object(or null) to `obj1` it will not affect the second reference in the `getAction`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the IL generated for Main:

```
IL_0000:  ldstr       "x1"
IL_0005:  newobj      UserQuery+Foo..ctor
IL_000A:  stloc.0     // obj1
IL_000B:  ldloc.0     // obj1
IL_000C:  call        UserQuery.getAction
IL_0011:  stloc.1     // a
IL_0012:  ldstr       "x2"
IL_0017:  newobj      UserQuery+Foo..ctor
IL_001C:  stloc.0     // obj1
IL_001D:  ldloc.1     // a
IL_001E:  callvirt    System.Action.Invoke
IL_0023:  ret
```

from which i deduce that when you call `getAction()`, it creates method with values in it for `obj1`, when you are are creating a new instance and invoking the delegate, due to closure it has previous value in its compiler created method, due to which it prints **x1**

When you are calling `getAction(obj1)`, `Foo obj` is now referring to new Foo("X1")`` , then you are doing `obj1 = new Foo("x2")` , now `obj1` is has reference of `new Foo("x2")` but `Foo obj` of `getAction(Foo obj)` is still referencing to `new Foo("x1")`

```
obj1 = new Foo("x1")  // obj1 is referencing to ----> Foo("x1") memory location
getAction(obj1)  // --> getAction(Foo obj) obj is referencing to Foo("x1")
obj1 = new Foo("x2") //  obj1 is now referencing to----> Foo("x2") memory location
// but in getAction(Foo obj) obj is still referencing to Foo("x1")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your code to

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo obj1 = new Foo("x1");
        // rewrite of
        // Action a = GetAction( obj1 );
        Foo obj = obj1;
        Action a = () => Console.WriteLine( obj.name );  

        obj1 = new Foo("x2");        
        a();                         
    }
}
```

That is what internally happens. You assign the reference to `obj` and build an action that refers to `obj`.

Answer (score 1):

You explaination is correct and is basically a way of rephrasing what is written in the C# Language Specification in [Section 5.1.4](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691167(v=vs.71).aspx) (reported here for completeness, emphasis mine):

> A parameter declared without a ref or out modifier is a value
>   parameter.
>
> A value parameter comes into existence upon invocation of
>   the function member (method, instance constructor, accessor, or
>   operator) (Section 7.4) to which the parameter belongs, and **is
>   initialized with the value of the argument given in the invocation.** A
>   value parameter ceases to exist upon return of the function member.
>
> For the purpose of definite assignment checking, a value parameter is
>   considered initially assigned.